# json array in jquery return data undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pull data to continously refresh some news from a source

data.php

```
$fecha = $_GET['fecha'];
$feed = array();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM envivo WHERE fecha >= '".$fecha."' ORDER BY fecha DESC");
$existe = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($existe != 0) {

    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $jsondata = array();
        $jsondata['titulo'] = $data['titulo'];
        $jsondata['link'] = $data['link'];
        $jsondata['fuente'] = $data['fuente'];

        $feed[] = $jsondata;
    }

    echo json_encode($feed);
}
```

live.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Live</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function restults(data) {
    $(data).each(function() {
        $("#envivo").append("<li>Titulo: " + data.titulo + " Link: " + data.link + " Fuente: " + data.fuente + "</li>");
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fecha = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            data: "fecha="+fecha,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "data.php",
            success: function(data){
               restults(data);
            }
        });
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="envivo">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When running index.php, data.php it's called via ajax, and it returns something like this

> [{"titulo":"Test
>   1302662957","link":"http:\/\/www.google.com","fuente":"Zuker"},{"titulo":"Test
>   1302662957","link":"http:\/\/www.google.com","fuente":"Zuker"},{"titulo":"Test
>   1302662631","link":"http:\/\/www.google.com","fuente":"Zuker"}]

Everything fine at this point... now i'll try to retrieve and append that data

on firebug console

> [{"titulo":"Test
>   1302662957","link":"http:\/\/www.google.com","fuente":"Zuker"},{"titulo":"Test
>   1302662957","link":"http:\/\/www.google.com","fuente":"Zuker"},{"titulo":"Test
>   1302662631","link":"http:\/\/www.google.com","fuente":"Zuker"}]

So it's fine... but when using

```
$(data).each(function() {
    $("#envivo").append("<li>Titulo: " + data.titulo + " Link: " + data.link + " Fuente: " + data.fuente + "</li>");
});
```

i'm getting undefined for each value... any ideas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$.fn.each()` is designed to iterate over dom elements. You want `$.each()`, which iterates over any generic collection, like an array of objects, for example. Change your `.each()` code to something like this:

```
$.each(data, function(index, data) {
  $("#envivo").append("<li>Titulo: " + data.titulo + " Link: " + data.link + " Fuente: " + data.fuente + "</li>");
});
```

Comment: Saved my girlfriends day. Trying to help her with her Json + php thing! :) Great !